# Amazon SQS polling causes CPU overload?

Tags: cpu-usage, amazon-sqs, worker

I have a Ruby on Rails app that queues tasks to be processed by a script attached to ProcessManager. This script uses long polling to get items from SQS (Receive Message Wait Time = 10), but CPU usage skyrockets once long polling starts and crashes the host.
I know for a fact that its not an issue with the processing part. What gives?

Comment: SQS long polling mostly IO use (not CPU), you should use some profiling to check your problem.

Comment: Can you just poll occasionally (with time in-between), rather than using long polling?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Shoryuken](https://github.com/phstc/shoryuken). I don't get CPU overloads using it.